# Не работает клиентская часть socket.io при запуске на любой странице, кроме index.html

Tags: javascript, modx, socket.io

Работаю с socket.io, запускаю на 3000 порту. CMS ModX, если важно, хотя в данном случае я не пользуюсь админкой. Когда запускала на главной странице через index.html, все было нормально, сервер работал, когда я вводила мой_хост:3000. Затем мне нужно было переместить приложение в файл game.php, написала то же самое, в файле сервера поменяла строку `res.sendFile(__dirname + 'index.html');` на

```
res.sendFile(__dirname + 'game.php');
```

Теперь я не знаю, как запустить клиентскую страничку. Пробую мой_хост:3000/game.php или мой_хост/game.php:3000 - получаю 404 ответ сервера

Мои файлы (тестовая версия из примера в руководстве)
app.js (сервер)

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.sendfile('game.php');
});

//Whenever someone connects this gets executed
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
   console.log('A user connected');

   //Whenever someone disconnects this piece of code executed
   socket.on('disconnect', function () {
      console.log('A user disconnected');
   });
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
   console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

game.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello world</title>
   </head>
   <script src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
   
   <script>
      var socket = io();
   </script>
   <body>Hello world</body>
</html>
```

Как запустить код на стороне клиента на страничке, отличной от главной?

Comment: Попробуйте заменить строку `var http = require('http').Server(app);` на `var http = require('http').createServer(app);`

Comment: @Pr0gramm1st попробовала, ошибка та же

Comment: А ещё такой момент в строке `res.sendfile('game.php');` не должно разве быть `res.sendFile('game.php');`? И путь `'game.php'` указан точно верно?

Comment: @Pr0gramm1st "не должно разве быть" - вы две одинаковых строчки указали.
путь game.php указан, думаю, верно, так как при указании другого пути при попытке запустить мой_хост:3000 сразу выводилось, что такого пути нет, а с этим путем выводится все верно

Comment: В выражении `sendFile` "File" с большой, вроде как, пишется. К сожалению, сейчас не могу проверить, но, кажется, Интернет не врёт)

Comment: @Pr0gramm1st увы, так тоже не сработало

Comment: А что будет, если вы измените `game.php` на `game.html`? Я сам новичок по socket.io, но вот, начитавшись, выяснил, что вы пытаетесь в браузере запустить через sendFile() PHP-файл! Полагаю, php-код всё же должен выполняться на сервере

Comment: @Pr0gramm1st ну так у меня внутри html-код, думаю, на расширение в имени файла ему будет пофиг)
а вообще, попробовала game.html, выдает то же - Cannot GET /game.html

Comment: А сам файл game.html лежит в той же директории, что и index.html, с которым текущий код работает?

Comment: Мне просто всё не даёт покоя, что должно быть:
1) расширение .html
2) `res.sendFile(__dirname + 'game.html');`

Comment: @Pr0gramm1st, да, у меня в той же директории лежит game.html, и строчка res.sendFile(__dirname + 'game.html'); у меня именно такая, я туда добавила __dirname